# Import two pybind11 .pyd Modules from same C++ source code

Tags: python, importerror, pybind11

Having a fully functional .pyd Python module generated with pybind11, assume the C++ source code involved changes a little bit but the exposed interface between C++ and Python remains constant. If we compiled before the changes we would obtaind a slightly different .pyd objects as compiling afterwards.
How can I import both .pyd modules in Python and use them accordingly? Until now if I naively generate them e.g. by changing the code and saving the .pyd files in different locations I can import the first module and I get the next error while importing the second one:
ImportError: generic_type: type "foo" is already registered

Comment: Normally the new module is a *replacement* for the old one. So you would never import both. If the new one contains a `foo` that is different, then you should call it something different like `bar`.

Comment: Thanks! that solved it by the way. I created different namespaces and voila!